# Error in PHP code to update a table

Tags: php

I am facing an error in this following function in my class.

```
<?php
  if(isset($_REQUEST['customer_id'])){

    $customer_id = $_REQUEST['customer_id'];

  }
      ?>
<?php     
 if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{

$data = array(

        $_POST['customer_name'],
        $_POST['customer_address'], 
        $_POST['customer_phone'], 
        $_POST['customer_email']
        );

var_dump($data);


$update = DB::update('customer',$data,$customer_id,'customer_id');
```

Error message is :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens' in
```

What is the issue here? I missed anything i dont see the issue with my sleepy eyes...

var_dump result is:

```
 array (size=4)
 0 => string 'Foo M' (length=5)
 1 => string 'Foo Lab' (length=17)
 2 => string '2147483647' (length=10)
 3 => string 'foo@moo.com' (length=11)
```

Comment: There is missing relevant code

Comment: The error message is not complete, it should include a filename and line number.

Comment: Which PHP Framework is this? (`DB::update` ?) Where is the SQL-query you are using? The error alone tells you, that you are passing in more parameters than there are placeholders (e.g. question marks `?`) in the SQL-query.

Comment: @Jocelyn …which is useless, unless you have the complete code-base available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the problem is that you are specifying too many columns or too many values for those columns in your sql statement. You have col1, col2, col3.... val1, val2... <-- too many columns for the number of values OR vice versa.... col1, col2.... val1, val2, val3.

Try to echo your query before it is executed and you will see the mismatch.

Comment: Nice comment, errh I mean Copy'n'Paste from the PHP docs. This is not really an answer.

Comment: If he doesnt want to lookup the error then I will tell him what the definition is - I also told him how to see the error. I love you bad mannered people :D

Comment: yes... The issues was with  $data = array(
            'customer_name' => $_POST['customer_name'],
            'customer_address'=>$_POST['customer_address'],
            'customer_phone'=>$_POST['customer_phone'],
            'customer_email'=>$_POST['customer_email']

            );

Comment: New its shows Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by  .

Comment: that is a different error, please post a new question. p.s. there are plenty of links on google about the header error, checkem out!